# unmet dependencies when installing PyQt5 on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5

installing pyqt5 on ubuntu gives the following error messages:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
...
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.3-1+focal1 is to be installed
 libpython3.10-dev : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.3-1+focal1 is to be installed
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: ....
 python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.3-1+focal1 is to be installed
 python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.3-1+focal1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to solve the issue with the following code that shows the results.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 109785 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.3-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 3.10.3-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.3-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 3.10.3-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you done what the error message suggests?

Comment: yes I tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. It returned another error.

Comment: "another error" is meaningless to us. **What** error?

Comment: Sorry, the error is too long and it does not fit in comments. I have to add it at the end of question.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below commands to clear any issues then try again.

```
apt-get check
apt-get --fix-broken install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get autoclean 
apt-get clean
```

Then remove the broken python files

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib 
sudo apt install libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib 
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: `sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
sudo: appstreamcli: command not found`

Comment: I found this solution:
`sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib`
`sudo apt install libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib`
`sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`
This forces the libpython3.10-stdlib to be removed and reinstalled properly. Apparently, `apt-get --fix-broken install` is not removing the files properly.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer accordingly to reflect the changes

Comment: Where is the :heart: icon? This solved my issue. Thanks so much @David